# What is the meaning of "But he argues that Mr Trump’s cultural heft is an advantage as it has not been since 2016."?

Tags: meaning

From [The Economist](https://www.economist.com/united-states/2023/12/20/why-donald-trump-is-gaining-ground-with-young-voters)

> But he argues that Mr Trump’s cultural heft is an advantage **as it has**
> **not been since 2016**.

Actually, Mr Trump's cultural heft has been an advantage since 2016. But why "as it has not been since 2016" is used, not "as it has been since 2016"?

Comment: The piece is reporting the opinion of someone else. I fail to see what the issue is here. Your personal opinion on the subject is irrelevant.

Comment: "as" is not simply a subordinating conjunction but is carrying meaning that invokes degree, manner, or quality.  If it is replaced with "which" the meaning would change.